# ASP.NET Core Identity two factor token works even after it was used once

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I know that two factor token from ASP.NET Core Identity is time-based. Is it possible to restrict the two factor token after it was used once?

```
await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider);
```

Comment: The token is a cookie and you can delete the cookies after it is used.

Comment: @jdweng: the question possibly covers a scenario where the token is reused from another browser (probably by a hostile entity).

Comment: The OP asked "Is it possible to restrict the two factor token after it was used once?"

Comment: I think token is not stored as a cookie, and also by default our two factor token providers are not stored in the database. Do I need to implement our own token provider and store them somewhere and verify that they are only used once?

Comment: Yes, we have done that with an extra store for used tokens